# Is it possible to kill one or all session in server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, razor

My question is in the title,

I would like to kill a session in server side using session id or other...

Thanks for your responses

Comment: I think you are a little bit confused. **Session is per user**, so you don't need his session id to clear/remove any session. Use `Session.Remove("sessionItemName");`.

Answer (score 1):

`Session.Abandon` maybe?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx

HttpSessionState is fully documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx

Edit - Oh I see, you want to kill some *OTHER* session, from another separate session? I'm don't think that's possible from the MVC/webapp side of things.

Maybe an IIS extension?

Comment: I can stop application on IIS directly but if there is a mean to do that differently ?